# How to align logo next to navigation?

Tags: html, css, navigation, alignment

This is what it looks like: [image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/j9yr75.jpg]

How would I correctly vertically align the navigation with the logo?

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="" title="" class="logo">Logo</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="" class="mg">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="" class="mg">Chat Now</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="" class="mg">Mobile Chat</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="" class="mg">Report User</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-nav {

}

.menu-nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

.menu-nav ul li a{
color: #fff;
margin: 10px;
}

.menu-nav ul a.mg {

 }

.menu-nav ul li a.logo {
background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
height:60px;
display:block;
width:215px;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) This is your first question moderation and I dont have to complain about anything. Let me inline that picture for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly align?"  Do you have a sketch of how you would like for your header to look?

Comment: I already fixed it with help from BuddhistBeast, but thank you! :)

Comment: You can also solve this by using margin-top or padding-top on the non-logo list elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a display method named `table` to the ul tag and then include a display method `table-cell` with `vertical-align:middle` to effectively, vertically align your links to the logo.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-nav">
    <ul class="a">
        <li><a href="" title="" class="logo">Logo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="" title="" class="mg">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="" title="" class="mg">Chat Now</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="" title="" class="mg">Mobile Chat</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="" title="" class="mg">Report User</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a{
    display:table;
}
.a li{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Which is better seen through this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVDGX/3/)

EDIT:

You can update your margin by giving the li tags a class and calling that specific class. This can also be found in the JSFiddle above and you can play with it a bit as well.

Comment: Really helpful and effective thank you, another quick thing how would I use margin specifically on the links without interfering with the logo itself?

Comment: @Jack_Saurus You can use `.mg` or `.menu-nav li:not(.logo)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code i have just added `line-height:60px;` for `.menu-nav ul li a`

**HTML :**

```
<div class="menu-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="" title="" class="logo">Logo</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="" class="mg">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="" class="mg">Chat Now</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="" class="mg">Mobile Chat</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="" class="mg">Report User</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu-nav {

}

.menu-nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

.menu-nav ul li a{
color: #fff;
margin: 10px;
line-height:60px;
}

.menu-nav ul a.mg {

 }

.menu-nav ul li a.logo {
background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
height:60px;
display:block;
width:215px;
padding: 0;
}
```